# Find entries in sql that were done milliseconds against each other

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to debug an issue I found with someone else's code, where it reads both the id and the timestamp for a key. But, I noticed that it is not reading the millisecond information. While this is a potential cause, this not confirmed, and I need to find out if this is the cause.

The problem could occur if two entries in the table happened within the same second, 10:20:05.0500 pm and 10:20:05.5000 pm, but not 10:20:05.5000 and 10:20:06.0500.

How do I write such a query to look for it?

I am using Oracle pl/sql.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle to use fractional seconds a column must be of data type "**TIMESTAMP**".

Maybe someone else's code is using a variable of type **DATE**, which is year-month-day hour-minute-second without fractional seconds.

[Database SQL Language Reference: Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm)

Can you give the table description and someone else's code?

Comment: Its timestamp on my side, no idea on their side.
But, we send information to them with a feed. The feed did not contain the millisecond information.

Comment: Who is _"their side"?
What is a "feed"?
You said "send information" using what format?

Answer (score 1):

To find records with the same date/time up to second precision but with different milliseconds, you can compare different records by joining the table to itself

```
SELECT A.ts, B.ts
FROM
    Test A
    INNER JOIN Test B
        ON TO_CHAR(A.ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = TO_CHAR(B.ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE
    A.ts < B.ts
ORDER BY
    A.ts, B.ts;
```

`TO_CHAR` truncates the milliseconds. This is important, because functions that round could yield different seconds. E.g., `CAST(ts as timestamp(0))` rounds, which is not what wee need.

The example from the link below has a record with 999 milliseconds to test this.

See [example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1acab/1/0).